# Scrapy can't find div tag in google docs

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to get the text "data" using scrapy from the link https://docs.google.com/document/d/1owRcDbh6vKuohojMhFD_2d4ivGM9J-nDziVRJR9Djck/edit?usp=sharing which is a google docs.
My code is

```
import scrapy


class MitdataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mitdata'
    allowed_domains = ['www.docs.google.com']
    start_urls = ['https://docs.google.com/document/d/1owRcDbh6vKuohojMhFD_2d4ivGM9J-nDziVRJR9Djck/edit?usp=sharing']

    def parse(self, response):
        text = response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="kix-appview"]/div[7]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div/div/div/span[2]/span/span/text()[1]').extract()
        goodhtmlcode = response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="kix-appview"]').extract()
        badhhtmlcode = response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="kix-appview"]/div[7]').extract()
        print(text)
        print(goodhtmlcode)
        print(badhhtmlcode)
```

Output is

```
[]
['<div id="kix-appview" class="kix-appview"><div id="docs-findbar-id" class="docs-ui-unprintable"></div><div id="docs-spellcheckslidingdialog-id" class="docs-ui-unprintable"></div><div id="docs-checkupdialog-id" class="docs-ui-unprintable"></div><div id="docs-suggestiondialog-id" class="docs-ui-unprintable"></div><div class="kix-appview-editor-container"><div class="kix-appview-editor"></div></div><div id="kix-vertical-ruler" class="docs-ui-unprintable docs-vertical-ruler docs-ruler"><div class="docs-ruler-inner"></div></div></div>']
[]
```

I don't get why is just stops finding elements. It is able to find everthing down to `//*[@id="docs-suggestiondialog-id"]` and then it skips over anything in between `//*[@id="docs-suggestiondialog-id"]` and `//*[@id="kix-vertical-ruler"]`. Am I missing something
obvious?

Comment: Are you trying to scrape a Google Document? I suggest you save all the content as csv instead

Comment: Yes, thanks I will try that it might be easier because the real google document I am looking at has many tables and cells with text but gave me the exact same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Here is code.

```
import scrapy
class MitdataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mitdata'
    allowed_domains = ['www.docs.google.com']
    start_urls = ['https://docs.google.com/document/d/1owRcDbh6vKuohojMhFD_2d4ivGM9J-nDziVRJR9Djck/edit?usp=sharing']

    def parse(self, response):
        text = response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="kix-appview"]/div[7]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div/div/div/span[2]/span/span/text()[1]').extract()
        goodhtmlcode = response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="kix-appview"]').extract()
        badhhtmlcode = response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="kix-appview"]/div[7]').extract()
        print(text)
        print(goodhtmlcode)
        print(badhhtmlcode)
        print()
        print(response.css('span::text').get())
        print()
```

Here is out data.

```
[]
['<div id="kix-appview" class="kix-appview"><div id="docs-findbar-id" class="docs-ui-unprintable"></div><div id="docs-spellcheckslidingdialog-id" class="docs-ui-unprintable"></div><div id="docs-checkupdialog-id" class="docs-ui-unprintable"></div><div id="docs-suggestiondialog-id" class="docs-ui-unprintable"></div><div class="kix-appview-editor-container"><div class="kix-appview-editor"></div></div><div id="kix-vertical-ruler" class="docs-ui-unprintable docs-vertical-ruler docs-ruler"><div class="docs-ruler-inner"></div></div></div>']
[]

data
```

Comment: Your code finds the title of document and not the table cell. It is my fault for picking the title to be the same as what were in the cell.